Postman Setup for API v4
Can someone help provide examples of how to set up a couple of quick APIv4 calls using Postman? I seem to be having issues testing out v4 (v3 calls are ok).
This is my setup:

It's a POST call using https://example.org/civicrm/ajax/api4/Contact/get
In Headers, I have a Key of X-Civi-Auth with a value of Bearer <My API Key>
In Body, I have x-www-form-urlencoded selected, and I have a Key of "params" and a Value of {"where": [['id', '=', 2016]]}

But running that always returns the first 25 contacts, not the single contact I'm looking for. So I must be doing something wrong in the syntax of the params or maybe a Postman setting I'm not thinking of? I have "encode url automatically" on. It must be something simple that I'm just not seeing.
I'd appreciate any pointers/examples.
